# How do I create an Angular Project using the CLI that uses Pug3?

Tags: angular, angularjs, npm, pug

I created a project using the following...

```
ng new my-app
cd my-app
npx ng add ng-cli-pug-loader
```

But I get

```
.../my-app on branch main > npx ng add ng-cli-pug-loader
npm WARN cli npm v10.2.3 does not support Node.js v22.0.0-pre. This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.
ℹ Using package manager: npm
✔ Found compatible package version: ng-cli-pug-loader@0.2.2.
✔ Package information loaded.

The package ng-cli-pug-loader@0.2.2 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
✔ Packages successfully installed.
CLI's Webpack config was not found. Try running `npm install` before running this tool.
```

How do I get this to work so I can add the pug library?

Comment: Since v17, new projects are setup to use Vite/Esbuild instead of Webpack.  That probably would explain the issue.